# CSS - Strange behavior of table cell border only in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a simple table with css. When I add a bottom border to the middle row, the next row has a really weird border. it happens only in chrome, and I have no idea why.

I should say the I apply the bottom border to the middle row using javascript (because I don't know the size of the table beforehand). I tried to apply without javascript, and it works without the weird problem.

here is an example of the table, notice the borders in the middle:
http://ri-cloud.appspot.com/super_tacticko?create

here is the javascipt I'm using to create the middle line:

```
// add the middle line
var half = height / 2; // it has to be zugi anyway
var $middle = $('tr').slice(half-1, half);
$middle.find('td').addClass('middle-td');
```

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 25 (Mac OSX 10.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If resizing the window fixes the issue (as it does in my case also) it is most likely a rendering bug... Chrome has a number of these that spring up from time to time, mainly because it tries to be faster than everything else by cutting corners (imo).

The only way to work around a bug is to keep trying different approaches until you find one that doesn't trigger the issue, either that or try programatically resizing your table/body after it's been created and then put it back to the right size again — this may force Chrome to redraw correctly... and should occur quickly enough that the users wont notice. A third approach could be to build the table entirely in JavaScript and once properly formed, embed it into the page.

The reason why the CSS method probably works is because it will be using Chrome's rendering methods at a different point in the rendering process to that of the JavaScript style modifications.

Basically, I have seen Chrome do some pretty strange things. The hacks I've used in the past to get around odd Chrome problems have been:

1. Use decimals in dimension calculations — i.e. `30.1px` instead of `30px`
2. Not setting opacity to full — i.e. `0.99` instead of `1.0`
3. Not to use an ip address prefixed with a `.` when setting a cookie
4. Use `overflow: hidden` to repair strange renderings in certain situations.

*Oh just for the record I'm viewing on Windows 7 via Chrome v25.0.1364.97*

Comment: ok, got it. for now, what works is:  $middle.next().find('td').css('border-bottom', '0');

Comment: @MosheShaham Good old Chrome :) glad you found a fix.

Comment: From my observations this usually happens in Windows when you set the screen scale to something besides 100% -- example: https://i.imgur.com/9m0SaIp.png

Answer (score 1):

I have run into similar problems in Chrome on Windows 10. The cause of this problem is that Chrome is not working correctly with Windows text-size settings feature (IMHO changing DPI in Win OS). When I have switched from 125% text size to 100% text size, Chrome was rendering my HTML table correctly. As far as I have been testing, other browsers are working with this feature OK.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made a quick fix to this issue as follows:

```
table {
  tr td {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    outline: 1px solid #666;
  }
}
```

It is not bullet-proof, the sizes of borders are 2px, but better something than nothing.